# sudo apt-get update error ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apt, gedit, software-sources, gksu, etc

Hi I'm new in Linux and I need your help :)

Every time when i type sudo apt-get update it shows:

```
alphaog@alphaog-HP-Pavilion-DV7:~$ sudo apt-get update
E: Type 'ain' is not known on line 3 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ricotz-testing-precise.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

I tried

```
gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and put # in front third line but it still doesn't work. 
Please Help! :)

Comment: Can you post a pastebin of your sources.list?

Comment: That was the wrong file to edit, see answers.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to fix.

`apt-get` gives you a warning about where the problem exists.

> Type 'ain' is not known on line 3 in source list
>   /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ricotz-testing-precise.list

Open the file with an editor (eg: gedit). You will need root privileges to edit the contents.

Run this command in terminal

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ricotz-testing-precise.list
```

**and delete the word 'ain'** . Save the file and run again

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: @user111172 Glad it works ! Please mark the answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please provide output from: (add detail to your question)

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ricotz-testing-precise.list
```

---

You will likely need to remove the third line from this file:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ricotz-testing-precise.list
```

- Enter your password (if asked) and wait for editor.
- Delete the 3rd line.  *The "ain" is a corrupted " main".*
- Save, and Close the file.

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: when i type cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ricotz-testing-precise.list